# continioulsy send data with ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I make an ajax request where the script can append something to the request a long time after (minutes) the headers were sent? How do I do this with jquery?

This would be very useful in chat applications. Then there hasn't to be one request per message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge this is not possible. What is usually used is [long-polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling). Long polling involves having a long living request on the server which polls the datastore and sends a 200 response when data is available. Since sending messages is initiated from the client the message can be sent as a single AJAX call, there is no need to have a living HTTP request. **Note: Long-polling is used for server to client communication**. As I said I am not sure if what you want to do is possible, but in any case the overhead of having a full HTTP request sent from the client for each message is not worth trying to optimize away.

If you want a long lived socket connection you should consider using [socket.io](http://socket.io/). It's a perfect match for the use case of a chat.

This [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socket-io-and-expressjs/) describes how one can implement a chat using socket.io. By the way socket.io isn't restricted to a Node.js backend, there exists implementations for many different languages. A google search for the term `socket.io server implementations` turns up a lot of results.

Comment: If the goal is to **send** stuff, you're not polling. Details. Yes, websockets.

Comment: Well no I know the goal is to send stuff, I explained how client to server long-polling works, I might have expressed myself poorly. Anyhow I made it clearer in my answer. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not done in chat applications.

If you go to Facebook.com and look for how the messages are sent, you will see each message is sent directly when <kbd>Enter</kbd> button is pressed. Because once the request is sent to the server, the connection between two of them is disconnected untill a responce is ready.

You want to send the headers and then keep joining the data, right? Well for that you will need to keep the request active at the server side. I am not sure why you want this. But if you just want to create the Chat application, then here is my refer

Either use http://www.asp.net/signalr (SignalR) or send the messages to a domain, lets say a subdomain where the cookies aren't used. So only text information is sent and recieved.

But note that you'll have to send a new request everytime the message has to be sent. I have not used SignalR for my apps but I have tried reading their documentations which has a detail of its work and it is used in such type of usage.

Comment: The connection isn't really disconnected. The HTTP request is ended. (The TCP socket stays open for 5 min, so the browser does append stuff at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in plain javascript.

If your web app is intended to run on recent browsers you may use **HTML5 Server-Sent Events (SSEs)**

Take a look here: http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/killing-a-library

Or here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/